# Updating databse in mysql found the error binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

Hi I am new in mysql and I have facing error at the time of dump. Error is:

```
"ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option--binary-mode is enabled and my sql is run in non-interactive mode. Set--binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected. Query: ''my database size in greater then 1 gb"
```

Comment: Can you share some code how you are trying to perform that ?

Comment: i am trying with mysql workbeach with pprocess import database GUI mode

Comment: Please show the code causing this!